# Why the size of the object is zero

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, size

I am getting the sizeof of object as zero, which is ought not to be. Please explain me the concept as why the compiler is giving this answer?

```
  #include<iostream>
  using namespace std;

  class xxx{
      public: int a[];  // Why this line is not giving error.
  }; 

  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
      xxx x1;
      cout<<sizeof(x1); //Q=Why this code is not giving error.
      return 0;
  }
```

Comment: int a[] seems like a nonstandard C++ extension to me (C99?). Once such extension is used, it is not unreasonable to expect other parts of the language (sizeof) to behave nonstandard as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the others have said, an object in C++ can never have size 0.

However, since the code isn’t valid C++ in the first place (arrays cannot be empty) this is inconsequential. The compiler just does what it wants.

GCC with `-pedantic` rejects this code. MSVC at least warns. My version of `clang++` with `-pedantic` ICEs but does emit a warning before that.

Comment: @Klaim No, straight up ill-formed, if I read the standard correctly. `xxx` is an incomplete type according to §8.3.4 and `sizeof` on an incomplete type shouldn’t be allowed (§5.3.3). I’m uncertain whether it requires a diagnostic though.

Comment: So compilers let it work...for allowing some optimization tricks?

Comment: @Klaim It’s a GCC extension that is present to create compatibility with C99, which allows “flexible array member” (but only as members in structs).

Comment: I simply used the g++ standard compiler and this was the result. Since I am not an expert in c++ I was unable to explore other options.

Comment: Is it like any parsing error done by the g++ compiler. I simply executed using g++ -o option.

Answer (score 2):

You're not using a standard-compliant compiler. An object size can't be `0`, even an empty `class` or `struct` has size `1`. Moreover, the array dimension has to be specified.

EDIT: It's strange, ideone also prints out 0. In MSVS I get a warning, but at least the size is 1.

#### 5.3.3. Sizeof

> 1. [...] When applied to a class, the result is the number of bytes in an object of that class [...] The size of a most derived class shall
>      be greater than zero. [...] The result of applying sizeof to a base class subobject is the size of the base class type. [...]

EDIT 2:

I tried the following in MSVS:

```
xxx a[100];
```

and it fails to compile. Strange how it doesn't pick up the error beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

That element `a` in your class `xxx` is called a flexible array member.

Flexible array members are not in the C++ standard. They are a part of C99. However, many compiler vendors provide flexible array members as a C++ extension.

Your code as-is is not legal C code. It uses C++ specific constructs. Your code is easy to change to C. Change the `class` to `struct`, get rid of the `public`, and change the use of C++ I/O to C's `printf`. With those changes, your converted code is still illegal C99 code. Flexible array members are only allowed as the last element of a structure that is otherwise non-empty.

Apparently your vendor took the flexible array member concept over to C++, but not the constraint that the structure be otherwise non-empty.

Answer (score 1):

The size of an object can not be zero. even if  the class is empty, its size is never zero.

Checkout the link to know more [Bjarne Stroustrup's C++ Style and Technique FAQ](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html).